# Sparkly_Apply with Coxph function

Tags: apache-spark, sparkr

I am trying to run coxph() survival function with Spark_Apply, but I am getting below error

```
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") :
  cannot open file 'C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\1\Rtmpusw8Aw\file344868ef1e07_spark.log': Permission denied
```

I saw this error whenever I did gave a wrong R command, but in this case my coxph command working fine in R

Spark_Apply with Linear regression reference
https://spark.rstudio.com/

I know spark_apply just try  to distribute the data as much as it can. In my question I want to know I am doing in mistake or spark_apply canot run the survival models or should I need to import survival function by any way to sparklr R.

R Code:

```
coxph(Surv(t_start, t_stop, t_trans)~1,data_input)
```

O/p:

```
   Null model
      log likelihood= -XXX 
      n= XX
```

Sparklr code:

```
data<-copy_to(sc,data_input)

spark_apply(
  data,
  function(e) coxph(Surv(t_start, t_stop, t_trans)~1,e),

)
```

O/p:

```
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") :
  cannot open file 'C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\1\Rtmpusw8Aw\file344868ef1e07_spark.log': Permission denied
```